# go dep and go generate

Tags: git, go, dependency-management, godeps

### How can I add go dependencies that are auto-generated?

I have a protobuf-repository with a single go-file in its root, which contains the following:

```
//go:generate ./scripts/generate_go_sources.sh    
package protobuf
```

The mentioned script goes through all `.proto` files in a "message/" subfolder, and generates the go-sources.

Afterwards, the repository contains a lot of subpackages like

```
ptyes/package1/file.go
ptyes/package2/file.go
```

I do not want to check these files in to version control.

### How can I use this repository with go dep?

I'm trying to switch to go dep for dependency-management, but I cannot convince it to download this repository and execute "go generate".

```
Solving failure: No versions of github.com/company/protobuf met constraints:
        master: Could not introduce github.com/company/protobuf@master, as it is not allowed by constraint vendoring from project github.com/company/myProject.
        develop: Could not introduce github.com/company/protobuf@develop, as it is not allowed by constraint vendoring from project github.com/company/myProject.
        vendoring: Could not introduce github.com/company/protobuf@vendoring due to multiple problematic subpackages:
        Subpackage github.com/company/protobuf/ptypes/package1 is missing. (Package is required by (root).)      
        Subpackage github.com/company/protobuf/ptypes/package2 is missing. Package is required by: (root)
```

go dep discovers the correct repository (vendoring-branch), but discards it because it cannot find the required sub-packages. They are only here once "go generate" was called in the root package.

Comment: "How can I use this repository with go dep?" -- You don't. Go dep and go generate are unrelated tools.  The only way to get `go dep` to work with generated files is to commit them to version control. Why do you not want to do this?

Comment: @Flimzy the protobuf files are also used by other languages (Java), so I cannot commit the go-source in that repository - I would need a separate repository, with the protobuf-definitions as a submodule. And every time the protobuf files are changed, someone would need to update the source-repository as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's the nature of generated files. Fortunately, CI scripts can enforce that very easily (or even automate it, if you desire).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the godep documentation about [migration](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/migrating.html):

> dep assumes that all generated code exists, and has been committed to
>   the source.

Therefore, it seems to be impossible to do what I want. The solution is to create a repository which contains the generated sources, and make sure these sources are automatically generated and kept in-sync with the actual source data (in my case the raw *.proto files).

Since I cannot put the generated sources into the same repository as the source data, it is neccessary to completely synchronise these two repositories (same branches, same tags), so that the versions used by go dep are somehow useful when comparing with the actual repository, that only contains declarations.